# PHP : No readable output, when I use the less than symbol, in combination with the var_dump() function

Tags: php, string, atom-editor, var-dump, elementary-functions

Why is in PHP this code snippet returning no readable output,

```
$string = "<Hello World!";
var_dump($string);
```

but this

```
$string = ">Hello World!";
var_dump($string);
```

is returning

```
">Hello World!"
```

Comment: Oh dear, it's getting worse! if you only use the less than symbol '<' then var_dump prints it, but why not in combination with letters?

Comment: What's your PHP version? I can't reproduce this

Comment: cannot [reproduce](https://3v4l.org/E8Nil)

Comment: I'm using the newest interpreter version 7.4.2 in combination with the Atom texteditor. I run my code on a webserver also with the newest version. I display the results vie Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that you dump this var in html file and browser parse this:

```
"<Hello World!"
```

as

```
<hello world!"="" <="" body="">
</hello>
```

This snippet

```
$string = ">Hello World!"
```

can't be parsed as html tag, so you can get readable output.